# Need to provide spaces between cells in UITableview in ios

Tags: ios6

I need to provide space between cells in UITableview.And I am also posting an image which consists of here two cells[image: image is here].I have gone through previous posts,but I am unable to find a suitable answers.
Thanks coders

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, and none as simple as you may expect, the two ways that come to my mind right know are:

- Define your custom cell to add an space on bottom by playing with the foreground background. If you dont need the space (for instance at the last cell) resize the cell to hide it.
- Use a grouped table with one section per cell so you can use that section as space